# @RequestBody being set but not sure how

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

So this is a super novice question. Im running [this tutorial](http://blog.springsource.com/2010/07/22/spring-mvc-3-showcase/) and in some of the methods like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/string", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String readString(@RequestBody String string) {
    return "Read string '" + string + "'";
}
```

where there is a string as a requestbody, the string is foo but i don't know how it is set. Is there some method somewhere that sets a default or what (maybe i'm missing something super obvious). The html looks like this

```
<form id="readString" class="textForm" action="<c:url value="/messageconverters/string" />" method="post">
    <input id="readStringSubmit" type="submit" value="Read a String" />
</form>
```

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand the "@RequestBody String string" variable is being set by Spring when you submit your html form using the using post request method.